# How can I use pipes in Unix to find specific calendar dates?

Tags: unix, calendar, grep, pipe

I'm trying to find the number of Sundays in the year 2011 that are on the first of the month.

The commands I've used so far are ncal -y 2011 | grep "Su" | grep "1" | wc. I'm not getting any output unfortunately. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

`ncal -y 2011 | grep "Su" | grep -ow "1" | wc -w`

`grep` parameters explanation:

```
-o      Print each match, but only the match, not the entire line.
-w      The expression is searched for as a word (as if surrounded by
         `[[:<:]]' and `[[:>:]]';
```

The `-w` paramter searches for '1' as the entire word, to prevent hitting numbers like 12 which also contain a '1'. The `-o` parameter prints the match only instead of the whole line, so it can be processed by `wc`.

`wc -w` counts only the words, so you only get the word count as the output, in this case `1` - only one Sunday on the first of the month in 2011.